# Grails auto-reloading new controller actions

Tags: grails, groovy, reload, spring-loaded, grails-2.4

I've

1. created new Grails 2.4.3 project
2. created `TestController`
3. set `grails.reload.enabled = true` in `BuildConfig.groovy`
4. run application with `grails -reloading run-app`

My controller action code:

```
def index() {
    render "test"
}
```

When I change the string `test` to `test2`- I see in console (in Eclipse):

```
..................
|Compiling 1 source files
```

And after reloading page I see `test2` - ok.

But when I try to add new method:

```
def test3() {
    render "test3"
}
```

I see:

[image: error result]

**Why?** Why there isn't even the url?

Example - action does't exist:
[image]

Interesting thing is - when I create a whole new controller the `index` action of the newly created controller works...

**EDIT**

After a while I decided to go with spring-boot and as a matter of fact - there it's not working either. I think that springloaded is the issue here because it doesn't pick up added new method in `@Controller`

Comment: Did you add view page corresponding to test3 action?

Comment: The `render` method overrides this behaviour (of finding some view for an action). If I had returned model then it should search for a corresponding view. But yes - I've tried this also: with the same effect.

Comment: Im stuck here, did you find anything to solve this @Xeon ?

Comment: Same issue, only a restart reload new actions in controllers. Changes in existing actions are reloaded right.

Comment: @VitorHugo, @IsidroGH - it's `spring-loaded` issue. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've asked the same question on [github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/10#issuecomment-53155999).

It seems that latest spring-loaded SNAPSHOT is **working fine**.

But it must be integrated into Grails - maybe in the next release unfortunately :(

Comment: overwrited the old spring-loaded jar in grails-2.4.3\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars with the latest build and it worked, thank you Xeon.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of reporting [this issue to Grails](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2773).

Answer (score 1):

Solution that works for me:

1) Versions:

- IDE: Intellij IDEA 14.1.3
- JDK: jdk1.7.0_25
- GRAILS: 2.5.0

2) On BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.reload.enabled = true
grails.project.fork = [
        test: false,
        run: false,
]
```

3) Originally, my code was compiled on grails 2.4.4, so I upgraded to 2.5.0. I had no problems with the version change with plugins or anything. My guess is this works because it uses later versions of spring-loaded. Steps:

- set-grails-version 2.5.0
- clean
- delete directory work (just to be sure, I don't really know if this is good practice)
- compile and/or go to number 4

4) Debug Idea with this configuration: run-app -reloading

---

Works perfect, no forked debug, reloading enabled, no console error after reload and all breakpoints working even after code changes!

Comment: I have tried the all the above steps but auto reloading not working. My environment is as below:

    IDE: Intellij IDEA 2016.2
    JDK: jdk1.8.0_101
    GRAILS: 2.5.4