# Grails 2.4.3 app auto reloading not working

Tags: grails, spring-loaded

Unable to reload grails application at runtime, My current development environment: 

`Grails app version 2.4.3
JDK: 1.7.0_21`

I have added following setting in my BuildConfig file

`grails.servlet.version = "3.0"
grails.reload.enabled = true`

**Some links**

After going through different stack overflow links such as,

- [Grails auto-reloading new controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443800/grails-auto-reloading-new-controller-actions)

  I Checked `springloaded` jar file, tested app by replacing jar with snapshot jar from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/releases/tag/1.2.1.RELEASE).
- [Checked java version required by Grails 2.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961601/is-java-1-8-0-required-for-grails-2-4-3)

  After checking some `JIRA` issues, I upgraded my Java version to latest java `1.7` version and tested app.

What is affecting to reload app at runtime?

Comment: what have you changed since it last worked? are you running forked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working`

Comment: @cfrick I am not running forked mode. In previous grails version 2.3.5 it was reloading properly but in upgraded grails 2.4.3 it's failed to reload. 

By the way, my colleague's have same grails app with 2.4.3 version and JDK 1.7.0_55 installed. Their app is reloading properly. Is there any system software related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots many debugging and checking online resources I succeeded to reload my app

Solution:
While running my grails app, I come across some java ioexception (user limit of inotify watches reached) which was restricting reloading of my grails app.

1. Updated system inotify watch limit [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached)
2. Replaced springloaded jar shipped with grails 2.4.3 with snapshot version
   (Check this link https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11728)

Answer (score 1):

grails -reloading run-app

after this your application starts reloading automatically.

Comment: this is very obvious that after grails 2.4 > for reloading grails app we need to use above command you mentioned.